# Can i create collection list inside a collectionlist in shopify? is it possible

Tags: shopify

I have already created four tiles in a webpage using shopify a,b,c,d. I want to create a subcategory of list inside a. Is it possible or not ?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! can you please add a sample code to help us help you better? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default it is not possible to have nested collections, or subcollections.

There are several ways to achieve it.

1. Using nested menus.
2. Using handles of collections, modifying the handles of collections like
   collection: "men" then set the child collections like "men-shirts", "men-shoes", and code the theme to work these handles.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create collection inside collection, however you can create nested menus:

[Nested Menus](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/building-nested-navigation)

With nested menus you can pretend like you have nested collections

Comment: Thank you for your reply